# i have installed nodejs in ubuntu and checked its version and it installed correctly but npm does not get installed correctly

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu

I have installed nodejs using the command :

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

and I checked nodejs version by `nodejs --version` and it shows `v7.10.1`

after that i have checked the npm version using `npm --version` and it shows error.

```
    /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:6
    let url
    ^^^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word
        at Module._compile (module.js:437:25)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
        at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
        at require (module.js:378:17)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/access.js:5:11)
        at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```